# Binding with collections and Lists

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone please tel me an example for how to bind the data with the Collections and Lists. I know how to bind the data with databound controls. But, binding with the collection and Lists sounds little bit tougher.

Thanks.

Regards,

Naren.

Comment: What do you want to bind with collections, what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to bind the data with ArrayList.

Comment: What language? Can you show some code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Collection.Add or Collection.AddRange where Collection can be any of collection like ArrayList in your case to add your data to the collection.
There is no binding involved here.
Binding is done in between data and controls.
Collections are used for collecting the data and no binding is involved.

Comment: if you like my explanation.Please visit codespread.com for more posts.